# Sending Email in Proof-of-Concept Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, deployment

I have a Rails app I've built that's a simple clone of a popular online service. I built it originally while in a class and am still playing with it now that I'm done. I'm using Ryan Bates' letter_opener gem to fake sending signup confirmation emails in development and that works perfectly. The app is deployed to Heroku so I can show people what I can do but the mailer obviously doesn't work in deployment. I've done some research and if this were an actual site offering services I'd have to setup accounts to send the emails from using Google Business or MailChimp or the like. What I'm wondering (since the site will only send an email occasionally) is if this is still the best way to do things or if there's some simple way to get the functionality without going through lots of setup.

Has anyone had experience with things like this previously? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a Gmail account for sending emails. Take a look at [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) which comes in Rails and use that to send your emails. Take a look at section 6.2 in particular which tells you the configuration you need for GMail

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure if it could be as simple as just using a gmail address or not. I'll try this and accept assuming I can get things to work.

Comment: Took forever to get around to this, but you confirmed what my research had suggested. Thanks!